# How do I generate GUID under Windows Mobile?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, guid

Is there a ready-to-use API (C / C++) in Windows Mobile ecosystem that I could use to generate a GUID? I am looking for simple one-shot API to do this. If there is a need to write a whole algorithm or use some extra 3rd-party modules, I will do away without this.

**Background**. To display notification to the user I use SHNotificationAdd, which requires a GUID for it. Examples in MSDN and other sources show that GUID is hard-coded. However, I want to wrap the SHNotification* within a class that blends well within the overall design of my application. MSDN is very shy on details on what SHNOTIFICATIONDATA->clsid represents. The "class" mentioned raise more questions than it answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to generate a GUID for SHNOTIFICATIONDATA.

You only set the clsid if you want WM to notify a COM object that implements IshellNotificationCallback interface.

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458065.aspx):

> When loading up the SHNOTIFICATIONDATA
>   structure, you can specify either the
>   notification class (clsid), the window
>   to receive command choices (hwndSink),
>   or both. If you specify the clsid,
>   your COM component must implement
>   IshellNotificationCallback. If you
>   specify the clsid and an hwndSink,
>   both COM and Window Message-style
>   callbacks will be generated.

I've never personally used the COM callback, I always use the windows message callback.  It's a lot easier to setup and use and you don't need to generate a GUID.

Answer (score 5):

Use [CoCreateGUID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886229.aspx) for Windows Mobile...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use UuidCreate (which CoCreateGuid eventually calls).

Comment: According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205(v=vs.85).aspx ) `UuidCreate` is available for desktop applications only (which makes one wonder what `CoCreateGuid` actually does on Windows Mobile).